# Is there a way to integrate the product of two functions numerically in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I have two functions which take multiple arguments:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

gamma_s=0.1 #eV
gamma_d=0.1 #eV
T=298 #K
homo=-5.5 #eV
Ef=-5 #eV
mu=0 #eV just displaces the function

#Fermi-Dirac distribution
k=8.617333262e-5 #eV/K
def fermi (E:float, mu:float, T:float) -> float:
    return 1/(1+np.exp((E-mu)/(k*T)))

#Lorentzian density of states
gamma=gamma_d+gamma_s
def DoS (E:float, gamma:float, homo:float, Ef:float) -> float:
    epsilon=homo-Ef
    v=E-epsilon
    u=gamma/2
    return gamma/(np.pi*((v*v)+(u*u)))
```

I know that if I want to integrate just one of them, say `fermi`, then I would use

```
quad(fermi, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(mu,T))
```

But I need the integral of their product `fermi*DoS` with respect to their common variable `E`, and I can't imagine how to do it with `quad`, since there is no mention of it in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad).

I guess I could define another function `integrand` as their product and compute its integral, however that sounds somewhat messy and I would prefer a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I get `NameError: name 'mu_s' is not defined` when I try to run the provided code. Obviously, `T_amb` and `k` are also undefined.

Comment: My first instinct is to create a new function which returns `fermi(E, mu, T) * DoS(E, gamma, homo, Ef)` and pass this function to `quad`, but that's the best I can do without more info

Comment: `quad` as you gather from its docs takes one function, with scalar input and output.  The `args` just "go along for the ride".  I don't see what messy about providing a new function that returns the product.  Does basic calculus tell you that there's something better?  Remember, `quad` is a straight forward numerical integration - evaluate a selected values and sum.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Ok, I've changed it so that it can be reproducible. ```mu``` just displaces the origin of the function, as I've commented. Also, doing the ```integrand``` function is also my instinct, but I have to perform several different integrals and I don't want to write a bunch of functions just to use them once. That's why I asked if there is a cleaner way to do it in Python.

Comment: @hpaulj I was asking if there is a way to insert in ```quad``` the product of those two functions, which is another function (consistent with the definition of ```quad```), and also pass all of their ```args``` in some way so that it does the integral with respect to ```E``` (1-D integral).

Comment: I don't see the problem with defining functions that only get used once.  You could write them as lambdas, but that doesn't make the code any more efficient.  Are you more concerned with the code efficiency, or your typing efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to define a new, standalone function if something inline is more appealing to you:

```py
quad(lambda e: fermi(e, mu, T) * DoS(e, gamma, homo, T), -np.inf, np.inf)
```

That is, we [use partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) to turn the product of `fermi` and `DoS` into a new Python `lambda`.

Just to give some mathematical justification for the need to do something like this...

Mathematically speaking, one can only integrate (integrable) functions (or elements of function spaces derived from integrable functions). To integrate the *product* of two functions, we have to say which function is meant by their product. After a while, this may feel obvious, but here I think it's worth noting that humans **defined**

*(fg)(x) := f(x)g(x)*.

In the same way one must give mathematical meaning to the product of functions, one must give meaning to the product of two Python functions. Especially because Python functions can return all sorts of things, many of which make no sense to multiply, so there couldn't be a general definition.